# Resource not found for the segment 'x'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm getting this error: Resource not found for the segment 'GetTest'.

Code is like this:

```
    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<string> GetTest()
    {
        var tmp = new List<string>();
        return tmp.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Can we see your client implementation?  How are you calling it?  Is it possible that it would return null?

Answer (score 0):

"Resource not found for the segment" raise when looking for a primary key that doesn't exist

try it with try-catch

```
try  
{  
   var tmp = new List<string>();
   return tmp.AsQueryable();
}  
catch( DataServiceQueryException ex )  
{  
   return null;
}
```